# React Styled Components conditional ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to conditionally style a box with three different colors depending on the value of my test.

```
if test = A or B, it needs to be yellow
if test = C, it needs to be green,
if test = anything else, it needs to be blue.
```

I would rather write a switch or if/else, but I don't know if its possible to not use a ternary operator with Styled Components.

Comment: Can you post your component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`props => ...` is just an arrow function with implicit return, so you could give the arrow function a body and accomplish what you want with `if`/`else` statements.

You could use `props.data && props.data.test` to make sure that `props.data` is set before you try to access `test`.

```
color: ${props => {
  const test = props.data && props.data.test;

  if (test === 'A' || test === 'B') {
    return 'yellow';
  } else if (test === 'C') {
    return 'green';
  } else {
    return 'blue';
  }
}};
```

Comment: Didn't know you could conditional handling this involved inside of the styled-component itself, I thought it was just simple ternary true/false. Thanks for expanding my horizons.

Comment: How can I put `data` inside props before setting the color?